# Can't byte variable express 125 in Java?

Tags: java, byte, bytecode, not-operator

I'm totally java beginner and not good at English. So I don't know how to ask what I really want to know, but I trying..

After I learned some code about using byte I practiced. But the result was not what I expected..
below is my code!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    byte n1 = -2; // 10000010
    byte r1 = (byte) (~n1); // expectation: 125(01111101)
    System.out.println(r1);
}
```

but the result was "1"..

I learned that byte can express -128~+127 and I thought Eclipse would show me "125", but it was "1" so I want to know why..

Thank you for your attention to my question.

Comment: `(byte) (~n);` - do you mean `n1`?

Comment: -2 is represented by `11111110`, so applying Bitwise Complement Operator on it results in 1. `10000010` is `-126`.

Comment: It's negation, not xoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~x` is equivalent to `x ^ -1` in Java, so `~n1` is `-2 ^ -1 = 1`.

As Eran pointed out in the comments, the issue is that you are mistaken about the bitwise representation of `-2`. `-2` is `11111110`, while `1000010` is actually -126.

Comment: `~x` is also identical to `-x - 1`, which might be even easier to calculate in the head.